# Ссылка на GameObject, к которому прикреплен скрипт

Tags: unity3d

Здраствуйте
У меня есть в скрипте `GameObject`, являющийся объектом, к которому прикреплен скрипт. Проблема заключается в том, что сам скрипт прикреплен к нескольким объектам и надо получить из скрипта ссылку на этот объект. Получить по тегу или по имени не получается, т.к. у каждого объекта свой тег и своё имя. Не совсем понимаю как получить его из самого скрипта.
При попытке получить ссылку через `FindObjectOfType` находит первый возможный `GameObject`. Найти информации как получить в такой ситуации ссылку на объект не вышло, т.к. обычно находят объект через имя или тег.
Сам код

```
    using UnityEngine;

    public class SortGameObjects : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject Player;
        public GameObject EnemiAndBlocks;
    
        private void Start()
        {
            Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        }
    
        public void Update()
        {
            FindEnemiesAndBlocks();
        }
    
        private void FindEnemiesAndBlocks()
        {
            if (Player.GetComponent<Transform>().position.y > EnemiAndBlocks.GetComponent<Transform>().position.y)
                EnemiAndBlocks.GetComponent<Renderer>().sortingOrder = 2;
            else
                EnemiAndBlocks.GetComponent<Renderer>().sortingOrder = 0;
        }
    }
```

upd: проблема оказалась в том, что скрипт выполнялся даже без ссылки на объект, сам объект находился без проблем.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Любой компонент в Unity имеет ссылку на игровой объект, к которому он прикреплен. Это ссылка доступна через свойство `gameObject`.

```
private void Update()
{
        GameObject attached = gameObject;
}
```

[Документация по MonoBehaviour](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html)